# Is a linear model appropriate for this analysis?

Tags: regression

I have one continuous dependent which is measured as a concentration., one categorical IV and one continuous covariate. The min value of dependent variable is 0.05 and the max value is 70. I applied the linear regression. I have a big violation of assumptions. I was wondering if applying the linear regression is appropriate for this model. I tried to remove the outliers in order to improve the model but I could not fix the problem. Also, I took log of the dependent variable and I could make the distribution of the residual skew to the right. But since so many observations are less than 1, I am not sure wether taking the log is a good idea or not. I have a unbalanced design. And I want to compare the average of dependent variable around the level of independent which has four levels by adjusting age.Any advice?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tell us more about the response variable (is it a time? a ratio of two positive measurements? a rate? a concentration? an angle?), and what you're using the model to do. What questions are you trying to answer about the data/process? Is it for prediction of future observations, for example? Depending on what you're trying to do, a variety of alternative possibilities exist.

Comment: @ Glen_b, thanks for the comment, the dependent variable is C-reactive protein which is a continuous variable. I want to compare the average of this variable among the levels of the categorical variable by considering age as a covariate. I have an unbalanced design and the sample size in each level of the categorical variable is n1=22,n2=400,n3-50,n4=40

Comment: When you say " the dependent variable is C-reactive protein" you presumably mean it's some measure of an amount of protein in some sense. Is it (as I asked already) a *concentration* for example? A proportion in some other sense? A count? a volume? a mass? Some possible answers may make a difference to what may be suggested -- I wasn't asking idly.

Comment: Also, you should better add new information as an edit to the post, not only as a comment.

Comment: @ Glen_b, Thanks for the comment.  It should be in units of mg/L and is measured as a concentration.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by reading your residuals chart you should be able to quickly conclude an ordinary linear regression is not appropriate as your errors have very heavy tails and easily break the normality assumption of errors required under linear models.

To resolve this, you might try and log transform the response and do an lm on this and see if the resultant errors are more normal. However,  suggesting other models outside this spectrum is dependent on the data specifics.